# What does the "Lambda" in "Lambda calculus" stand for?

Tags: terminology, computation-models, lambda-calculus, history

I've been reading about Lambda calculus recently but strangely I can't find an explanation for why it is called "Lambda" or where the expression comes from.

Can anyone explain the origins of the term?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

An excerpt from [History of Lambda-calculus and Combinatory Logic](http://www.users.waitrose.com/~hindley/SomePapers_PDFs/2006CarHin,HistlamRp.pdf) by F. Cardone and J.R. Hindley(2006):

> By the way, why did Church choose the notation “$\lambda$”? In [Church, 1964, §2] he stated clearly that it came from the notation “$\hat{x}$” used for class-abstraction by Whitehead and Russell, by first modifying “$\hat{x}$” to “$\wedge x$” to distinguish function abstraction from class-abstraction, and then changing “$\wedge$” to “$\lambda$” for ease of printing. This origin was also reported in [Rosser, 1984, p.338]. On the other hand, in his later years Church told two enquirers that the choice was more accidental: a symbol was needed and “$\lambda$” just happened to be chosen.

Comment: And lambda is the name of the greek letter “λ” chosen as the symbol.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen even the wedge symbol has the form of the capital lambda in a sans-serif font (Λ).

Answer (score 10):

here is some other near-firsthand info/ angle on this by Church student Dana Scott as just reported by [Ghica](http://researchblogs.cs.bham.ac.uk/thelablunch/2016/05/why-is-lambda-calculus-named-after-that-specific-greek-letter-do-not-believe-the-rumours/) and documented in a youtube video.[1]

> He says that when Church was asked what the meaning of the λ was, he just replied “Eeny, meeny, miny, moe.“, which can only mean one thing. It was a random, meaningless choice. Prof. Scott claimed that the typographical origin myth was mainly propagated by Henk Barendregt and is just pure whimsy. He asked us to stop perpetrating this silly story.

[1] [Dana Scott on lambda notation](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=juXwu0Nqc3I) / youtube

[2] [why is lambda calculus named that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64468/why-is-lambda-calculus-named-after-that-specific-greek-letter-why-not-rho-calc) / math.SE